# 500 Internal Server Error when adding a line in the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-security

I need to add the following line into my `.htaccess` file in order to get my website working with mod_security

```
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

but then I get an error

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

In my WebHost manager I see the following message: "mod_security is installed and running!"

I do not know what I did wrong?

Comment: Check apache logs for details

Comment: In the logs I get the following message

[Wed Jan 13 18:29:12 2010] [alert] [client .............] /home/..../public_html/.htaccess: Invalid command 'secfilterscanpost', perhaps mis-spelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 4):

That module is probably not loaded. Try it within a [`<IfModule>` block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ifmodule) to avoid such error:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

But note that this doesn’t solve your problem. It just avoids that internal error.

To solve your problem, make sure that the mod_security module is loaded. This is done with the [`LoadModule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule).

Comment: In my WebHost manager I see the following message: mod_security is installed and running!

Comment: @Roland: Then your mod_security module is probably not intended to be used in a .htaccess file. Maybe it’s just allowed in the server/virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You said in your comments than in your log file you can read "invalid command 'secfilterscanpost', perhaps mis-spelled or defined"

If you are using mod_security2, the SecFilterScanPOST is obsolete and you should migrate it to SecRequestBodyAccessas , this is explained in the migration document.

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/ModSecurity-Migration-Matrix.pdf

Comment: Very helpful link!

Comment: This migration matrix is no longer available under that link.

Answer (score 1):

Check your apache error log (on linux it is usually in /var/log/http/error_log or similar).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the *SecFilterScanPOST* directive is allowed in *.htaccess* files (probably via an *AllowOverride* option in your Apache or VirtualHost config file).

Answer (score 0):

If your mod_security version is 2 or greater you can't put directives in a .htaccess file - [only httpd.conf will do](http://modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.11/html-multipage/configuration-directives.html). I suppose they'll add this to the FAQ sooner or later.